# Error message installing virtual environment Python 3.5 Linux Mint 17

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv

Linux Mint 17 with Python 3.5.1

```
$ python3 -m venv ENV_DIR
```

returns:

> Error: Command `'['/home/path/to/ENV_DIR/bin/python3', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']'` returned non-zero exit status 1

I have tried various ways to get the terminal to show I am in a venv with no success.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to indent your code sample by 4 spaces and the blockquote with > so that they render properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Please edit in to provide any additional detail that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good luck!

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do and how you got there, could you expand your question with more context?

Answer (score 0):

That's due to a bug in Ubuntu 14.04 (on which Linux Mint 17 is based)

You can either create the virtual environment without `pip` and then manually install it inside the environment:

```
$ python3 -m venv --without-pip my_venv
$ source my_venv/bin/activate
(my_venv)$ curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python
```

Or you can manually install `ensurepip` in your system, by adapting [these instructions](https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1804) to Python 3.5.1:

```
cd /usr/lib/python3.5
sudo mkdir -p ensurepip/_bundled

cd ensurepip
sudo wget https://github.com/akheron/cpython/raw/v3.5.1/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py
sudo wget https://github.com/akheron/cpython/raw/v3.5.1/Lib/ensurepip/__main__.py
sudo wget https://github.com/akheron/cpython/raw/v3.5.1/Lib/ensurepip/_uninstall.py

cd _bundled
sudo wget https://github.com/akheron/cpython/raw/v3.5.1/Lib/ensurepip/_bundled/pip-1.5.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
sudo wget https://github.com/akheron/cpython/raw/v3.5.1/Lib/ensurepip/_bundled/setuptools-
```