# Can't create a python virtual environment on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, python-venv

I'm a complete beginner to Ubuntu and I'm trying to create a virtual environment on Ubuntu 18.04. I had one running and it was working just fine, but I don't know what I did and know I cant get it to run.

I deleted my old `env/` file and now I'm trying to create a new one using

```
python3 -m venv env
```

but I get the following error

> Error: Command '['/home/user/app/env/bin/python3', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit s
>   tatus 1.

What gives?

Comment: Please try using `python3 -m pip --version` and tell us the message you get for this.

Comment: I get `pip 19.2.2 from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pip (python 3.7)`

Comment: I found this is a bug from Ubuntu, mind trying this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/37830577/10473393 (Please reply if it works)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the `python3-venv` package installed?

If not - install it with `apt-get install python3-venv` and try again `python3 -m venv env`

Comment: Honestly, I just ran so many commands I don't know what I just installed. But I ran something like this: `sudo apt-get install python3-pip python3-dev python3.7-dev` and things seem to be working now.

Comment: You can check it with ‘dpkg -p python3-venv’

Answer (score 1):

> just reinstall your python3-venv

```
apt-get purge python3-venv

apt-get install python3-venv
```

> and then create the virtualenv

```
 python3.7 -m venv venvTest
```

> if you have different version of python3, you should mention the exact python3 version. 
>   you can also migrate your python3.6 to python3.7 by following guide [migrate python3.6 to python3.7](https://dev.to/serhatteker/how-to-upgrade-to-python-3-7-on-ubuntu-18-04-18-10-5hab)